# inverting the summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers.

Then, how can one prove rigoroulsy that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j = \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j \sum_{n=j}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \text{ ?} $$

If one simply writes out the terms of the series on the left and the right hand side, the intuition is clear, but what is a proof?

Comment: Is the second summation contained within the first? Or are they just being multiplied?

Comment: @MatthewPereira it is contained in the first. note the index begins with $j$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you prove
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{K} \dfrac{1}{n^2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j = \sum_{j=1}^{K} a_j \sum_{n=j}^{K}\dfrac{1}{n^2}
$$
for positive integer $K$?  Will that help prove yours?

Answer (score 1):

You can think double indexes on rectangle. First if $j$ is from $1$ to $n$ horizontally, and $n$ is from $1$ to $\infty$ vertically, this form a lower triangle separated by $j\leqslant n$.

If you switch order of indexes and start with $n$ first, it is like switching to upper triangle in which $n$ is from $j$ to $\infty$ or $n\geqslant j$.